# The simulation tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, the tag [simulation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation) includes (at least) two broad categories of questions:

- Simulations in computability theory, i.e. simulate machines of type A with machines of type B.
- "Applied" simulations, that is algorithmically imitating some real-world thing.

While the two are clearly related -- they do the same thing, the difference lies in the object simulated -- I guess that the inclination of askers and groups of answerers are likely to be (almost) disjoint.

However, I don't have an idea how to meaningfully name more specific tags. Any ideas?

Comment: How about using [tag:machine-simulation] for simulation in computability theory?

Comment: @Kaveh Hm, simulating your favorite stapling machine could cause confusion then.